# website prompts non-admin user for login, other website on same server doesn't

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have two websites on the same server *(Win 2008 R2, IIS 7.5)* using the same application pool.  Both are set to use Windows Authentication.  I have my own user account, which is an admin account, and a tester "regular" user account with basic privileges.

**Website A** pulls up just fine for both accounts.

**Website B**, however, only pulls up for my admin account.  If I use the test account, it prompts for a login.  If I enter the test account's credentials, it prompts again, eventually resulting in a **401** error.

I've been searching for solutions and without finding an exact problem match, I have tried a number of things.

- giving the test account full disk access (not a prod server)
- different combinations of Negotiate and **NTLM** in providers
- verified allowed in Authorization Rules
- turning Impersonation on and off
- gave the app pool full access

In all cases it asks for a login if the test account is used, just on **Website B**.

In comparing the two sites, everything is setup similar, except now for changes I have been making trying to get **Website B** to work.

What else could cause this to work on one site but not on the other?  Are there other settings I can try checking or adjusting?

EDIT:

Here are my failed request trace results.

1st one:
[image]

The rest, of which there were 4:
[image]

I may be missing something, but I seem to be just getting that I had a 401 error, access was denied.  Is something in these that can point me in the right direction, given the information I gave above about assigning rights and comparing the two sites?

Comment: Have you looked at the "Failed Request Tracing" logs?  They should tell you why the 401 error was returned.

Comment: Edit above to include screens of the failed request logs.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that both websites are in the same "security zone" (in the internet explorer settings). The fact taht a site is in a wrong security zone is sometimes the reason for the security prompt to appear. Means, maybe this behavior has nothing to do with your website, but only with your user settings. If first site is "localhost" and second is "foo.bar" then try adding the second one to "intranet" zone.

Tools -> Internet Options -> Security

Comment: They are in the same intranet security zone.

Comment: Okay.. Maybe a stupid question, does user account have access to the second website folder, i.e. can you access the physical files using "test" user? Not using website, can you simply open that folder as "test" user?